# How do I create a for loop from a json file with many of the same fields and display it in html?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, iteration

I would like to be able to return a value that shows each game in a separate div on an html page. I know there would be some javascript in this which would allow for this to loop through the games. I'm just not sure what it is. Does anyone know how to display this data in html and javascript? I'd like to get the home team, the away team, and the scheduled field  for each game. Thanks in advance.

```
"games": [
{
  "id": "3950bf88-7d69-45cb-957f-9b73ffca1d6e",
  "status": "closed",
  "coverage": "full",
  "scheduled": "2015-10-28T00:00:00+00:00",
  "venue": {
    "id": "fd21f639-8a47-51ac-a5dd-590629d445cf",
    "name": "Philips Arena",
    "capacity": 18047,
    "address": "One Philips Drive",
    "city": "Atlanta",
    "state": "GA",
    "zip": "30303",
    "country": "USA"
  },
  "broadcast": {
    "network": "FS-SE",
    "satellite": "649"
  },
  "home": {
    "name": "Atlanta Hawks",
    "alias": "ATL",
    "id": "583ecb8f-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c"
  },
  "away": {
    "name": "Detroit Pistons",
    "alias": "DET",
    "id": "583ec928-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c"
  }
},
{
  "id": "f00b4cf7-4722-4ffb-8d6a-9d378f370228",
  "status": "closed",
  "coverage": "full",
  "scheduled": "2015-10-28T00:00:00+00:00",
  "venue": {
    "id": "38911649-acfd-551a-949b-68f0fcaa44e7",
    "name": "United Center",
    "capacity": 20917,
    "address": "1901 W. Madison St.",
    "city": "Chicago",
    "state": "IL",
    "zip": "60612",
    "country": "USA"
  },
  "broadcast": {
    "network": "TNT",
    "satellite": "245"
  },
  "home": {
    "name": "Chicago Bulls",
    "alias": "CHI",
    "id": "583ec5fd-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c"
  },
  "away": {
    "name": "Cleveland Cavaliers",
    "alias": "CLE",
    "id": "583ec773-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c"
  }
```

Comment: i'd suggest using d3js

Comment: mustache.js is an easy way to turn json into meaningful HTML

Answer (score 1):

this is a for loop to get fields you need.

```
 for(var i=0;i<games.length;i++){
  console.log('home'+i+games[i].home.name);
  console.log('away'+i+games[i].away.name);
  console.log('scheduled'+i+games[i].scheduled);
}
```

Comment: Woops my bad, there's two elements.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the array and fetch the corresponding keys. Then you can wrap those in any html element i.e. div, span, p. Also you can give styles to those elements as per your requirement.

In the following snippet, i have added a line break 'BR tag' and appended to body. Its a pure javascript implementation. You can put it in your specific container/div.

```
    var _innerHtml="";
    data.games.forEach(function(d){_innerHtml+=('scheduled:'+d.scheduled+', hometeam:'+d.home.name+', awayTeam:'+d.away.name+'<br/>')});
document.body.innerHTML=_innerHtml
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

            games = [
{
  "id": "3950bf88-7d69-45cb-957f-9b73ffca1d6e",
  "status": "closed",
  "coverage": "full",
  "scheduled": "2015-10-28T00:00:00+00:00",
  "venue": {
    "id": "fd21f639-8a47-51ac-a5dd-590629d445cf",
    "name": "Philips Arena",
    "capacity": 18047,
    "address": "One Philips Drive",
    "city": "Atlanta",
    "state": "GA",
    "zip": "30303",
    "country": "USA"
  },
  "broadcast": {
    "network": "FS-SE",
    "satellite": "649"
  },
  "home": {
    "name": "Atlanta Hawks",
    "alias": "ATL",
    "id": "583ecb8f-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c"
  },
  "away": {
    "name": "Detroit Pistons",
    "alias": "DET",
    "id": "583ec928-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c"
  }
},
{
  "id": "f00b4cf7-4722-4ffb-8d6a-9d378f370228",
  "status": "closed",
  "coverage": "full",
  "scheduled": "2015-10-28T00:00:00+00:00",
  "venue": {
    "id": "38911649-acfd-551a-949b-68f0fcaa44e7",
    "name": "United Center",
    "capacity": 20917,
    "address": "1901 W. Madison St.",
    "city": "Chicago",
    "state": "IL",
    "zip": "60612",
    "country": "USA"
  },
  "broadcast": {
    "network": "TNT",
    "satellite": "245"
  },
  "home": {
    "name": "Chicago Bulls",
    "alias": "CHI",
    "id": "583ec5fd-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c"
  },
  "away": {
    "name": "Cleveland Cavaliers",
    "alias": "CLE",
    "id": "583ec773-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c"
  }
}
                ];


        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>

    <script>
        for(g in games)
            {
                d = document.createElement('div');
                d.innerText = games[g].scheduled+games[g].home.name+games[g].away.name;
                document.body.appendChild(d);
            }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: just tick the answer plz

Comment: i did but it says I have to earn some reputation points to do so.